# A solution to this two-dimensional recurrence equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, pattern-recognition

I have a table of values that follows a specific pattern. The right and bottom edge are all ones. Let the table be indexed from bottom up and rigth to left, i.e 0,0 is at bottom right. A value at position $i,j$ is the sum of the values to the bottom of it, to the right of it and diagonally behind it. See below:
$$
\begin{matrix}
63 & 25 & 7 & 1 \\ 
25 & 13 & 5 & 1 \\
7 & 5 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
$$
Expressed as a recurrence relation:
$$S(i,j)=S(i-1,j-1) + S(i, j-1) + S(i-1, j)$$
$$S(0,j)=1 \ \forall j$$
$$S(i,0)=1 \ \forall i$$

How can I express $S(i,j)$ in a function? If possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with induction? This problem is a case where you guess a result and prove it by double induction, i.e. induction on each variable.

Comment: @IskyMathews I am familiar with the concept but I have never done it in 2d, but I will give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: @IskyMathews I think my problem is I have no idea what the guess should be. I have tried varying formulas like $3^(m+n)$ where $m$ is columns and $n$ is rows but it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

If you want, you can solve this using [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). In particular, if we write

$$S(x,y) = \sum_{x,y} s(i,j) x^i y^j$$

we can use your recurrence to find

$$S(x,y) = \frac{1}{1 - (x + xy + y)}.$$

Then we can get a closed form for $s(i,j)$ by getting a closed form for the coefficients in a taylor expansion of $S$.

Thankfully, though, this has been done for us. We can just [ask oeis](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C1%2C1%2C5%2C5%2C1%2C1%2C7%2C13%2C7%2C1&language=english&go=Search) for your sequence, and we find that it is the square array of "[Delannoy Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number)", and the linked wikipedia article contains a variety of formulas for your expression. Unfortunately, there's nothing I would *really* call a "closed form", but the fact that there isn't one on wikipedia (or on oeis, for that matter) is good evidence that one simply doesn't exist. This will save us the time of actually looking for one.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much!